# Is there any online programmer's community, focusing on core game development?

Tags: software-engineering

I am looking for a stricktly/mostly programming oriented game community, focusing on core graphics, middleware, and research. Any suggestions?

Edit: I am specifically looking for people/community/group, having expertise in core game engine design/programming, directx/opengl reservoir.(And specifically targetting the programming part only).(The platforms can be anything from PC to xbox360/ps3/wii and even 3ds.)

Comment: The technical forums on gamedev.net?

Comment: Is there something more specific you're looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "core"? Like in not-casual, not-mobile, not-social?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love these site for core game programming

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  (For problem and knowledge sharing)
- http://www.gamedevelopers.ie/ (Irish Game Development Community)
- http://www.gamedev.net/ (Game Developer Community)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which platform you are interested in making the games as there are numerous communities available focusing on 2D, 3D game development.

The question you are asking is very broad making it difficult for anyone to answer. So, please elaborate i bit more.

However if you prefer to tweek with the graphics part, you can opt for OpenGL.

In case of Android/iOS game development, Go for openGL ES.
If you prefer to go in desktop games development, go for openGL or D3D.

In case of android, as far as i know, there are many 2D and 3D engines available.

But if you are a starter, you should start from the book focusing on core openGL concepts. Hope this helps.

PS : i am unable to post this as a comment, So please don't mark DOWN my answer. I am a new member here.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question, which was about development communities.